# How to Display children on the Taxonomy term page?

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I think my problem is quite simple but I don't manage to find the solution on the internet (I found solution for Drupal 7, but they don’t apply to Drupal 8).

I have a taxonomy like :

- Fruits
  - Red fruits
    - Strawberry
    - Raspberry
  - Black fruits
- Vegetables

Using Views in Drupal 8, with the preconfigured Taxonomy term, I'd like that when I click on a parent, it displays all the children terms and the nodes within these children terms. *(eg. when I click on Fruits, it display all nodes in Fruits, Red Fruits, Strawberry, Raspberry and Black fruits ; and when I click on Red fruits, it displays all nodes within Redfruits, Strawberry and Raspberry).*

Indeed, by default, when you click on a parent term, it only shows nodes within this parent term, but not those who belong to children. *(eg. when I click on Red fruits, it only display nodes within Red fruits, but not those in Strawberry or Raspberry)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the solution. My Drupal is in french, I tried to translate, but my translation may not match the exact words :)

Go to *View* and edit the default *Taxonomy term (content)* page.
In *Contextual filters* :

1. select "possède l’identifiant de terme de taxonomie (avec profondeur)" and configure like this :

   - depth : choose the depth you want
   - check *Allow multiples values*
   - check *Provide a default value* and choose *Taxonomy term (ID) from URL*
   - select *Filter by elements that share all terms*
   - check *Override title* and write *{{arguments.tid}}* in the field
   - check *Specify selection criterion* and choose *Taxonomy term (ID)*
2. select "possède l’identifiant de terme de taxonomie avec modification de profondeur"

Now, if you have a complex taxonomies, go on a taxonomy term page may display the same result several times. To prevent this, in your *View*, go to *Other* section (under Contextual filters) and click on *Query parameters*. Then check *Distinct*.

Enjoy !

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]